# How can I read Secure Store Credentials using the Client Object Model?

Tags: client-object-model, secure-store

I got an high trusted provider hosted application that use the App Only Policy.
If I try to use server object model, sharepoint returns a context error.
Is it possible to use the client object model to read secure store credentials?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is something that is not possible, however you may create a custom web services instead as a work around.

This C# solution will be able to help you to build your web-services to get credentials,

[Retrieving Credentials from the SharePoint Secure Store using C#](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Retrieving-Credentials-95afbf80)

Comment: Hi Muhammad,thanks for the answer, but this is not the solution for me. Your example uses a SP webpart (that has a SPContext defined), instead, I need an example that help me to retrieve the credentials for a provider hosted apps with App Only Policy. In this envainment I don't have a valid SPContext.

Comment: @Domenico The example I have provided link for creates a proxy web services, and consumes it within a webpart, however what you need to do is to, create a web services similar to one in solution (in link), then call these web services in your highly trusted provider hosted application

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you need the credentials so as to connect to an external system from under the provider-hosted add-in. In this case you may not need the credentials as such, but you can create an external content type and access a list based on this ECT in order to read the data from the external system. So the solution may be:

1. Create an ECT for the external system you need the data from.
2. Create a list based on this ECT.
3. Read the list from your PHAI.